# Omniauth facebook sessions controller create action integration after Michael Hartl tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, railstutorial.org

I have just finished the Michael Hartl tutorial. I am trying to implement omniauth-facebook to sign-up and sign-in users. I am having trouble creating the master variable to use in the `create` action in the sessions controller. My assumption is that I should put in an `if else` statement to see if the master is either signing on through facebook or through the default form? Or should I use `and or` statement:

```
(master = Master.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase) || Master.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])) ?
```

Here is the omniauth-facebook sessons controller create action code:

```
def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

And here is my current sessions controller create action code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
        master = Master.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if master && master.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            sign_in master
            redirect_back_or master
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    .
    .
    .


end
```

Answer (score 4):

Whilst I might be late by one year to answer this question, I still think that new viewers with the same sort of problem like you had a year ago might benefit from the following answer

As I understand it the actual question is:

> How does one integrate **Facebook Authentication** with an **Authentication system that is built from Scratch**?

Since you said you used Michael Hartl's tutorial I went ahead and adapted my answer to an authentication system written by Michael himself. Now let's go over each piece of code one step at a time.

---

## ***1***

First of all we need to create two additional columns to our existing Users table for the **provider** and **uid** as follows...

`rails g migration add_facebook_auth_to_users provider uid`

...and add omniauth-facebook gem to the Gemfile...

**Gemfile**

`gem 'omniauth-facebook',       '2.0.1'`

Don't forget to run `bundle install` and migrate your database after.

---

## ***2***

Next we would need to go ahead and edit our Sessions controller...

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    if user.activated?
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      message  = "Account not activated. "
      message += "Check your email for the activation link."
      flash[:warning] = message
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end

def create_facebook
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  log_in user
  redirect_back_or user 
end
```

Sessions controller above contains two create actions. First one is the *untouched* method taken straight from the book, when the second one is a piece of code I used specifically for Facebook authentications.

Line `user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])` has two purposes. Create a user **IF** his/her unique facebook uid is not in the database **ELSE** log this person in the app if the uid exists. More on this later.

---

## ***3***

Next lets create a working **.from_omniauth** method that you briefly showed inside of your code in your question...

**user.rb**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name unless user.name != nil
    user.email =  SecureRandom.hex + '@example.com' unless user.email != nil
    user.activated = true
    user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 unless user.password != nil
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Here we try to find a user that matches the given `provider` and `uid` values from the hash and then we call `first_or_initialize` on the result of this. This method will either return the first matching record or initialize a new record with the parameters that were passed in. We then call `tap` on this to pass that User instance to the block. Inside the block we set various attributes on the user based on values from the OmniAuth hash.

You might be interested as to why did I put the `unless` statement after some of the attribute initializations. Well consider the situation whereby the user wants to update the profile, like change the name or smth, and then logs out. When that user finally decides to log back in, the `.from_omniauth` method will overwrite the User's in question update to the original facebook values, **unless** we stop it from doing so.

Also notice the use of `SecureRandom` library. Inside of the traditional authentication that was used by Michael Hartl inside his book, he introduces validations to email and password submissions. Emails must be neither blank nor taken. Likewise, a password has to be greater than 6 characters in length. Since emails have to be present and unique I decided to create **dummy** emails using `SecureRandom.hex + @example.com`. This will create a random hexadecimal string, like `52750b30ffbc7de3b362`, and append it to `@example.com`, hence generating the unique dummy email. Same goes for the password, however, I preferred to generate a random base64 string using `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`. The most important thing to remember that Facebook users don't need to know this information to login since that is the whole point of using Facebook authentication. This allows them to add this information with real data later on if they desire to do so.

---

## ***4***

Now would be a good time to add the button on the main application page for users to let them actually log in into the app...

**_header.html.erb**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  .
  .
  .
<% else %>
  .
  .
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %></li>
<% end %>
```

---

## ***5***

So, now we can send a request to facebook. One problem remains that we cannot actually handle the callback. To do so we need to do the following...

- Add `get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create_facebook'` to the **routes.rb** file
- Use convenient Javascript SDK provided by Facebook. Let's create a custom javascript file that uses this SDK...

**app/assets/javascripts/facebook.js.erb**

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
  return $.ajax({
    url: window.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js",
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: true
  });
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'your_facebook_app_id_goes_here',
    version: 'v2.3',
    cookie: true
  });
  $('#sign_in').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        return window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback';
      }
    });
  });
  return $('#sign_out').click(function(e) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        return FB.logout();
      }
    });
    return true;
  });
};
```

---

## ***6***

And that is it, except for one small caveat...

[image: problem]

If user decides to go and edit the profile, he/she would see our dummy email displayed right in the middle.This happends because Rails is smart enough to autofill User's information.In this case this, frankly, is quite embarassing. Good thing, however, that it is an easy fix. Just set the value to nil inside the form, like so...

`<%= f.email_field :email, value: nil, class: 'form-control' %>`

---

Hopefully this helps people who would like to go the route of building authentication systems from scratch :)

Comment: This is exactly I'm looking for. Thanks for testing. I will try your instructions in my app.
Thank you Miennie for sharing this problem. I'm going with Michael Hartl tutorial based user authentication system.

Comment: @TimKos  Thanks for your sharing. But I have just add config/initializers/omniauth.rb to your shared codes. When I click the "sign up with facebook", the page can not forward. What are you thinking about this situation?

Comment: @Timur In the function defined in user.rb I'm getting the error "undefined method provider for nil class" - any suggestions? I also had to change `'auth/:provider/callback'` to `'auth/facebook'`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was trying to integrate omniauth with the custom authorization code from the tutorial. After some research I decided to remove all the tutorial authorization code and go with Devise instead.

Answer (score 0):

Timur's answer is excellent, but assumes that the OP has already configured some things for OmniAuth. Unfortunately some readers will not have done the config and will get errors.
The minimum config for omniauth is to set up facebook credientials, make them available to the app and create a file called config/initializers/omniauth.rb with the following:

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :developer unless Rails.env.production?
      provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET']
    end
```

And of course, it would be wise to write some tests for this feature.

Neither this nor Timur's answer deals with the situation where a user has created a local login account, then tries to log in from Facebook. It will fail due to a duplicate email or create a new account if the Facebook email is different. the User.from_omniauth(auth) function should be updated to handle this case. omniauth has a page about how to handle this, but will require significant rework from Miachal's hartl's tutorial: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers